# GWT RPC response header

Tags: gwt, http-headers, response, rpc

Is there any way to read the header information received by GWT client, on the RPC response?

```
Response header
Server                 Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie             JSESSIONID=3379B1E57BEB2FE227EDC1F57BF550ED; Path=/GWT
Content-Encoding       gzip
Content-Disposition    attachment
Content-Type           application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length         209
Date                   Fri, 05 Nov 2010 13:07:31 GMT
```

I'm particularly interest in identifying when client receives the **Set-Cookie** attribute on its header.

Is there any way to do that on GWT?

I found that on

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter<T>
```

exist the method

```
public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) { ... }
```

On the parameter **Response** seems to have the information I need. The this is, exist some way to get that without "racking" the GWT compiler code?

thanks

JuDaC

Answer (score 1):

You may try to override the  `RpcRequestBuilder.doSetCallback` method and force your service to use it:

```
MyServiceAsync service = GWT.create(MyService.clas);
((ServiceDefTarget) service).setRpcRequestBuilder(new RpcRequestBuilder() {
    @Override
    protected void doSetCallback(RequestBuilder rb, final RequestCallback callback) {
        super.doSetCallback(rb, new RequestCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                String headerValue = response.getHeader("my-header");
                // do sth...
                callback.onResponseReceived(request, response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                callback.onError(request, exception);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Inspired by http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2009/12/22/custom-http-headers-with-gwt-rpc/

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your async service method to return a [RequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html) you should be able to set a [RequestCallback](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestCallback.html) that will be notified when the [Response](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/http/client/Response.html) is received. I haven't tried this myself, but it looks like what you need.

Comment: @Issac, can you explain more about your solution 

Thanks

Comment: @Vegeta Probably. What's your question?